# create n lists of list linq

Tags: c#, linq

[image]I have a simple list

```
var list =
            AppUtils.db.GetDataTable("dbo.RankSelectChart", view) // stopred procedure and getting datatable 
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(i => new 
                                   { 
                                     Date = i.Field<DateTime>("lastDatetime"),
                                     P1 = i.Field<decimal>("p1"),
                                     P2 = i.Field<decimal>("P2"), 
                                     P3..... P(n) 
                                   }
                               )
                       .ToList()
                       .OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

than i want to get a list of lists or dictionary like `List<Dictionary<Datetime, Decimal>>` means `Dictionary<Date, P1> .... Dictionary<Date, P(n)>`

how to write algorithm which is not depend how many P we have

Comment: One date with many P? I see your lastDateTime once

Comment: yes - 1 date many P -> list of 1 date, P1 ; list of 1 date , p2 ; list of 1 date, p(n)

Comment: Not clear : you wanna replace this code (because in your current code, you have to know all P(n)), or keep this code and do something on `list` ?

Comment: What is your expected result? I'm not clear why List<Dic<K,V>>

Comment: Do you really want is Dictionary<DateTime,List<decimal>>?

Comment: Why you are not clear i need to get `List<Dictionary<Datetime, Decimal>>`

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, you will need to use reflection to access the properties:

```
var result = new[]{"P1", "P2", "P3", ...}.Select(p => list.ToDictionary(
    i => i.Date, 
    i => i.GetType().GetProperty(p).GetValue(i)));
```

However, if you could avoid creating your list in the first place and just pull from the data table directly, it may be easier.

```
var dt = AppUtils.db.GetDataTable("dbo.RankSelectChart", view); // stopred procedure and getting datatable 
var pColumns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => c.ColumnName.StartsWith("p"));
var result = pColumns
        .Select(p => dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(
                i => i.Field<DateTime>("lastDatetime"),
                i => i.Field<DateTime>(p.ColumnName)))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If 'Date' is unique for all records in 'list', then you can use reflection to get the P(i) value for a record in list. Like so:

```
  // build sample data
  var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new {
      Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(x),
      P1 = new Decimal(x),
      P2 = new Decimal(x + 1),
      P3 = new Decimal(x + 2)
    })
    .ToList();

  // list partionned by date; assumes that Date is unique in list
  List<Dictionary<DateTime, Decimal>> partitionedList;

  if (list.Count == 0) {

    partitionedList = new List<Dictionary<DateTime, Decimal>>();

  } else {

    var n = 3;
    var listElementType = list[0].GetType();

    partitionedList = Enumerable.Range(1, n)
      .Select(x => {
        var prop = listElementType.GetProperty("P" + x);
        var pList = list.ToDictionary(
          ll => ll.Date,
          ll => (Decimal)prop.GetValue(ll));
        return pList;
      })
      .ToList();
  }
```

If 'Date' is not unique, then it cannot be the key to a dictionary and the desired data structure is not achievable.